# Why has Bitcoin Core stopped shutting down when Windows cleanly shuts down?

Tags: bitcoin-core, windows

Every night, I do this to turn off my Windows 10 machine:

```
shutdown /s
```

Note that there is no "forcing flag" or anything (`/f`).

Up until recently, Bitcoin Core appeared to always get the signal and cleanly shut down, just like every other application.

However, recently, whether it was a new version of Bitcoin Core or an update to Windows 10, Bitcoin Core has stopped shutting down when it gets the signal. The reason I'm convinced of this is that, every day when I turn the machine back on, Bitcoin Core (and only that program) appears to have been uncleanly shut down/killed suddenly, as it keeps having to resync the last several days. (Perhaps just verifying the local data rather than actually downloading it.)

I even tried keeping the Bitcoin Core GUI window open while shutting down one day, and I noticed that it didn't say the usual "Shutting down" text.

Whether this is Bitcoin Core's fault, Windows 10's fault, or a combination, the fact remains that this happens every single time now, and it's very annoying and worrying.

Is this issue known? Is it being worked on? What could be causing it? Would MS really change something fundamental about how applications are signaled when shutting down the OS in a minor update? (Not unthinkable.)

Comment: That sounds like a bug, and is very unlikely to be Windows' fault. Can you file an issue on https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues? Be sure to include information on which version of Bitcoin Core you're using, and which one was the last one that you know worked fine.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/99188/5406

Comment: @PieterWuille Actually, I literally cannot file an issue on Github. The site has not allowed me to register for years, much like virtually every other website. I have no idea how anyone uses the Internet anymore.

Comment: Try to get shutdown logs, bitcoin core logs about the issue and also try reproducing it on other machine with similar setup. [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) https://superuser.com/questions/345006/how-can-i-identify-the-culprit-of-my-slow-windows-shutdown/347191

Comment: @Prayank I don't have any other machine or the ability to sit and test stuff. But I did look in the Bitcoin Core log (again) and this is what it said the last before starting up again today: `warning='63 of last 100 blocks have unexpected version'`

Comment: @Shamarr logs will be helpful to narrow down the issue. Do you see any errors related to 'bitcoin qt' or 'bitcoind' in `eventvwr`: [Example1](https://i.imgur.com/LRxZJ2U.png) [Example2](https://i.imgur.com/EjCu9Y3.png) You can also check _System_  & _Applications and Services_ Logs in event viewer for shutdown if detailed logs are enabled in `gpedit.msc`. I will try to reproduce this issue on my system when I am free.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20052#issuecomment-702659790 you can use the PowerShell `Stop-Computer` cmdlet.